# Run a SELECT statement based on values in a Checkbox Array

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to run a SELECT statement based on the checkboxes selected by the user on the previous page. Each Checkbox has the ID of a Product as a value.

```
print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'. $row["id_product"] .'"></td>';
```

If they select checkboxes 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 I want the SELECT statement to select the product with the IDs 1 - 5. Here is what I have so far:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT reference, price, unit_price_impact FROM ps_product_attribute WHERE id_product = ". implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']) ."");
    echo $stmt;
    $stmt->execute();
    $product = $stmt->fetchAll();

    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
        echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
                foreach ($product as $row) {
                    print '<tr>';
                        print '<td>'. $row['reference'] .'</td>';
                        print '<td></td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row['price'] .'</td>';
                        print '<td></td>';
                    print '</tr>';
                }
        echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Why is the $_POST['checkbox'] value empty?

Comment: Because you didn't select any checkboxes?

Comment: btw `WHERE id_product = list of values ` is invalid query.

Comment: @u_mulder the user selects the checkboxes on the page before I run the SELECT statement.

Comment: @u_mulder so it isn't possible to select more than one row with a WHERE statement? i.e. where id_product = 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: It is possible with `WHERE IN ()` statement

Comment: @u_mulder so what is wrong with $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT reference, price, unit_price_impact FROM ps_product_attribute WHERE IN id_product = ". implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']); ."");?

Comment: Please, make sure you understand what you write here. `WHERE IN id_product`? Do you see logic here?

Comment: @u_mulder "SELECT reference, price, unit_price_impact FROM ps_product_attribute WHERE id_product IN = ". implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']) .""

Comment: Please, read manuals first.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ajax for reading the checkbox then in jquery you have to split/create an Array/object first and then send to php else if you are using form submit then its not an issue. Please try to Debug your code like below by using **isset()/empty()** to your code

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="a"><label>a</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="b"><label>b</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="c"><label>c</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['checklist'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['checklist'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
}
}
?>
```

Please Try with this Example for debugging Thank you